# Configuration DbSetup with Kotlin and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kotlin, dbsetup

I'm developing *Kotlin* application with

- *gradle*
- *Java 11*
- *Spring Boot 2.3.6.RELEASE*
- *DbSetup-kotlin:2.1.0*
- *testcontainers:postgresql 1.15.0*

After following this guide [DbSetup Kotlin](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/user-guide.html#kotlin) I'm facing problem with test configuration when I would setup my db during test phase.

builde.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.6.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "5.1.0"
    id("com.zoltu.git-versioning") version "3.0.3"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.72"
}

val openApiVersion = "1.5.0"

group = "com.adexm"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["testContainersVersion"] = "1.15.0"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest:${openApiVersion}")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:${openApiVersion}")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:${openApiVersion}")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")

    testCompileOnly("com.ninja-squad:DbSetup-kotlin:2.1.0")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${property("testContainersVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
}

tasks {
    withType<ProcessResources> {
        filesMatching("application.yml") {
            expand(project.properties)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test class

```
import com.adexm.timesup.service.ServiceTimesUp.RequestTask
import com.adexm.timesup.utils.tblTask
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.ninja_squad.dbsetup_kotlin.DbSetupBuilder
import com.ninja_squad.dbsetup_kotlin.dbSetup
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.get
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.post
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers
import javax.sql.DataSource

@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class ApiTimesUpTest(
    @Autowired val mapper: ObjectMapper,
    @Autowired val mockMvc: MockMvc,
    @Autowired val dataSource: DataSource
) {

    companion object DatabaseSharedPostgres {

        @Container
        private val postgreSQLContainer = PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>("postgres:12-alpine")

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun registerDynamicProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {

            registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl)
            registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername)
            registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword)
        }
    }

    fun prepareDatabase(configure: DbSetupBuilder.() -> Unit) {
        dbSetup(to = dataSource) {
            deleteAllFrom(tblTask())
            configure()
        }.launch()
    }

    @Test
    fun whe_getAll_then_taskIsPaged() {
        prepareDatabase {
            insertInto(tblTask()) {
                columns(
                    "task_id", "task_name", "task_note",
                    "created_by", "modified_by", "created_date", "modified_date",
                    "version"
                )
                values(
                    "dcbe2df3-c595-4c9c-abca-36210d5c24aa", "LfP", "kFnmH",
                    "", "", "2020-06-19 08:50:22.847536", "2020-06-19 08:50:22.847544",
                    0
                )
            }
        }

        mockMvc.get("/tasks") {
            param("name", "shelby")
            accept = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        }.andExpect {
            status { isOk }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test an exception is raised due to **ClassNotFoundException** and this is the few lines of error stack

```
Type com.ninja_squad.dbsetup_kotlin.DbSetupBuilder not present
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.ninja_squad.dbsetup_kotlin.DbSetupBuilder not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.LazyReflectiveObjectGenerator.reifyBounds(LazyReflectiveObjectGenerator.java:65)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.WildcardTypeImpl.getLowerBounds(WildcardTypeImpl.java:136)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:176)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:218)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:169)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:218)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.resolveInClass(TypeResolver.java:96)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:391)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:118)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:74)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:58)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1047)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:462)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:295)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:237)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.getBeanInfo(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:392)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Obviously I've made some mistake in my configuration maybe here

```
fun prepareDatabase(configure: DbSetupBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    dbSetup(to = dataSource) {
        deleteAllFrom(tblTask())
        configure()
    }.launch()
}
```

Which is the right way to set up **DbSetup**?
I think that also the way I'm trying to pass the DataSource to DbSetup is wrong

Comment: If it can find a class at compile-time but not run-time, then I'd expect the problem is more likely to be in your project set-up than in your code.  Can you post your `build.gradle` file?  Some more of the stack trace might help, too.

Comment: @gidds I've added build.gradle.kts file and the stacktrace of the error, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.6.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "5.1.0"
    id("com.zoltu.git-versioning") version "3.0.3"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.72"
}

val openApiVersion = "1.5.0"

group = "com.adexm"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["testContainersVersion"] = "1.15.0"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest:${openApiVersion}")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:${openApiVersion}")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:${openApiVersion}")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")

    testCompileOnly("com.ninja-squad:DbSetup-kotlin:2.1.0")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${property("testContainersVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }
}

tasks {
    withType<ProcessResources> {
        filesMatching("application.yml") {
            expand(project.properties)
        }
    }
}
```

In my **build.gradle** I made an error:

```
testCompileOnly("com.ninja-squad:DbSetup-kotlin:2.1.0")
```

instead of this

```
testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:DbSetup-kotlin:2.1.0")
```